# Javascript unit testing Promise.all synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, promise, sinon

I have a node.js application in which I have an object that maintains state and an update loop that updates this state every 30 seconds. Basically it is a build monitor that queries a build machine while serving the latest state of each pipeline to the frontend.

In the update loop I need to make several calls, for which I need all the data to make anything useful from it. Currently I wrap all these call in a Promise and use Promise.all to wait for them all to finish.

In the test I resolve each promise synchronously with the sinon-stub-promise package. This works perfectly for single promises. The problem however is that it does not work for Promise.all - at least synchronously. If I put a small timeout in my test then it passes fine.

Here are some snippets:

```
var pipelineRequests = pipelineNames.map(function(pipelineName) {
    return gocdClient.getPipelineStatus(pipelineName);
});

Promise.all(pipelineRequests)
    .then(function(values) {
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            // Do something now all data is available
        });
    });
```

So here I get a list of `pipelinesNames` and then create a request which returns a promise for each one of these pipelines. This works when I manually test it.

Now for the test code:

```
it("should wait for all to return before processing", function() {
        allPipelinesStub
            .returnsPromise().resolves({"NFT-Suite": ["Hour", "Overnight", "Weekend"]});

        pipelineStatusStub
            .withArgs("Hour")
            .returnsPromise().resolves({"status": "Passed", "build-number": 1, "upstream": ["GIT"]});

        pipelineStatusStub
            .withArgs("Overnight")
            .returnsPromise().resolves({"status": "Passed", "build-number": 1, "upstream": ["GIT"]});

        pipelineStatusStub
            .withArgs("Weekend")
            .returnsPromise().resolves({"status": "Passed", "build-number": 1, "upstream": ["GIT"]});

        var pipelinesService = require('../../src/services/pipelinesService');

        var pipelines = pipelinesService.getPipelines();
        should.exist(pipelines);
        pipelines.should.deep.equal({
            "NFT-Suite": {
                "Hour": {
                    "status": "Passed",
                    "build-number": 1,
                    "order": 0
                },
                "Overnight": {
                    "status": "Passed",
                    "build-number": 1,
                    "order": 0
                },
                "Weekend": {
                    "status": "Passed",
                    "build-number": 1,
                    "order": 0
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem is `pipelines` is `{}`. If a call `pipelinesService.getPipelines();` after a slight delay it works fine.

Testing these individually is fine because the stub resolves synchronously, I just can't find a way to force Promise.all to resolve after they all complete.

Is there a way to force this ? Or can I use sinon (or something else) to stub that out too ?

Appreciate any help

Comment: You have to return the result of Promise.all in the snippet above. In the test below return the Promise and chain a `then` block where you'll return the values returned from the promises.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. Promises are asynchronous. To test anything that involves them, write an asynchronous test.

Comment: I'm not sure if i got you problem, you're in trouble with test itself? If so, there's a parameter called done, so you can get it and call it on promise.all callback, look: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/best-practices-for-spies-stubs-and-mocks-in-sinon-js at "Async Tests with sinon.test"

Comment: Im trying to avoid doing it async with an arbitrary timeout because it just seems like there should be a better way. Id rather not return the promise.all because its not what that method is really for, its for updating the state based on the values returned the requests.

Comment: To run an async test you need to know when the async task complete. If a promise is not returned or the 'done' callback is not called mocha will automatically trigger a timeout after few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what you are testing. If you want to test the code using `Promise.all` you need to return the promise - or at least *some* promise to indicate that the operation has completed. It doesn't mean you *have* to return the promise from your existing code: you can wrap the logic in another, private, function "_foo" and let your existing code use that, and then test "foo" from the outside instead of your original code.

If this is inside `getPipelines()` the test would simply work if you just did:

```
return pipelinesService.getPipelines().then(() => {
    should.exist(pipelines);
    pipelines.should.deep.equal({ 
    // more code ....
});
```